# Onde por os arquivos?

Tags: java, spring, maven

Quando usamos Spring e Maven, qual o lugar que devemos colocar os arquivos? na pasta webapp ou na pasta WebContent?

Comment: Nunca ouvi falar de `WebContend`, nem `WebContent`. Só `java`, `resources` e `webapp`

Comment: acabei de corrigir, eh webcontent,

Answer (score 1):

Cada *IDE/Build Tool* possui sua própria maneira de estruturar um projeto Java, algumas são mais rígidas, outras mais flexíveis. As pastas que você citou não vão estar presentes em um mesmo projeto, já que fazem parte da estrutura de diferentes *IDEs/Build Tools*.

A pasta `WebContent` existe em projetos do Eclipse do tipo *Dynamic Web Project*.

A pasta `webapp` faz parte do [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) de um *Maven Web Project* (como o Maven se tornou popular, algumas outras ferramentas adotaram uma estrutura parecida, como o Gradle).

Como o seu projeto é um *Maven Web Project*, você deve utilizar a pasta `webapp` que, segundo a documentação do Maven, é onde deve ir arquivos como suas páginas JSP, `web.xml`, etc.

Comment: Sua resposta me fez entender a pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Depende muito de quais arquivos. Um exemplo claro é que arquivos properties por exemplo fica na pasta resource. Por outro lado, os arquivos java são colocado em sua estrutura de package, e a partir dai é possivel definir quais os pacotes que armazenam models, repository e até mesmo view.

Caso use thymeleaf por exemplo, há configuração especifica para fazer no arquivo xml de configuração do mesmo onde se pode definir em que lugar e qual a estrutura do arquivo. Na documentação é possivel encontrar a forma. Busque pela versão do spring, acredito que irá haver uma definição clara.

Poderia dar um exemplo mas há varias versões. Coloque uma a versão do spring e do mavem e posso até mesmo postar um exemplo basico(esqueleto).

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Amigo, 
Aqui onde eu trabalho, colocamos todo código relacionado ao Frontend (Javascript, Html, Css, Jquery..) dentro de WebContent (responsivo), onde há subpastas de organização (View, Model, Collection e template)...
Espero ter ajudado.